# Missing Feature issue while creating DataFusion Replication between Oracle to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir6GJ.png)

I am trying to create replication job in GCP DataFusion for connect between oracle to Bigquery. I can able to fetch the records from the database but getting below error at the last step. I have all permissions in GCP. What I missing here. Please help

Issue : We`re missing the necessary permissions to read from the source. Grant the appropriate privileges to the user account that is used to connect to your database, and try again. found when Validates that the given Oracle user has the required privileges on the customer's database.

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown from the Data stream side , when data stream is trying to read data from oracle.

You need to follow : https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/configure-your-source-oracle-database

Also the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/oracle-to-bigquery) might help. Main things that can cause the issue you are facing are

1. The Datafusion service account not having the right permissions
2. The dataproc service account not having the right permissions
3. The Oracle username/pwd not having the right privileges.